# How can I place a MouseOver event on a DiscreteBar Chart bar

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I'm trying to create a a bar chart using an NVD3 angular directive from here: http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/

The chart I'm using is this one: http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/discreteBarChart

This is my html for creating the chart on the page (the context doesn't seem to be important in this scenario):

```
                    <nvd3 options="options"
                          data="top10bar"
                          ng-mouseenter="mouseEnterEvent($event)"></nvd3>
```

This is the controller code (within which the  tag sits)

app.controller('BarChartController', function ($scope) {

```
$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'discreteBarChart',
        height: 350,
        margin: {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 55
        },
        width: 500,
        x: function (d) {
            return d.label;
        },
        y: function (d) {
            return d.value;
        },
        showValues: true,
        transitionDuration: 500,
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'X Axis'
        },
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
            axisLabelDistance: 30
        },
        tooltips: false,
        discretebar: {
            rectClass: ['discreteBar', 'tableRow']
        },
        interactive: true
    }
};

$scope.mouseEnterEvent = function (event) {

    console.log("EVENT!");
    console.log(event);
};

$scope.$on('elementMouseover.tooltip', function (event, data) {
    console.log("In scope.on");
    console.log(event);
    console.log(data);
    console.log("end");
});

$scope.$on('tooltipShow.directive', function (angularEvent, event) {
    angularEvent.targetScope.$parent.event = event;
    angularEvent.targetScope.$parent.$digest();
});
```

Of the three event handlers you can see at the bottom of the controller, only the first one works because I have an ng-mouseenter option specified in nvd3. However, this works when the mouse enters over the entire chart div. What I want is to detect a mouse over on an individual bar so that I can highlight it and then highlight another part of my view.

How would you go about doing what I'm trying to achieve here?
Any help is much appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to detect the event on the bar I have written the following.

```
$scope.mouseEnterEvent = function (event) {
    if (event.target.localName === 'rect') {
        /// Do your operation here.
    }
};
```

It worked for me. Hope it will help you, let me know if you find any better way to pass the event to chart itself.